# How to call mac API "Adding a new event" in swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, calendar, electron

I have an electron application, and a requirement is to call the mac's api to add related schedules, as shown in the figure:

[image: imgage]

I want to use swift for development, and then package it into a node addon for electron to call, but I am not very familiar with swift and mac api.

I don't know how to write related swift code and which api to call to complete the function of the above picture.

I tried `AppleScript`, but it seems that I can't choose calendar contains freely.

Here is the applescript code to try(unable to meet demand):

```
set theStartDate to (current date) + (1 * days)
set hours of theStartDate to 15
set minutes of theStartDate to 0
set seconds of theStartDate to 0
set theEndDate to theStartDate + (1 * hours)

tell application "Calendar"
    tell calendar "Calendar Project"
        make new event with properties {summary:"Important Meeting!", start date:theStartDate, end date:theEndDate}
    end tell
end tell
```

Of course, if `Objective-C` and `AppleScript` can also do it, it is also possible.

Any hints would be helpful. Thanks!

---

If the above description does not describe the problem well, then I will ask in another way:

What API of `macOS` should be called in swift to pop up a `Adding a new event` window

Comment: Hint: see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+add+event+calendar

Comment: @Willeke I have checked this before, but I haven't tried it specifically. Because what I understand from the problem description is to add directly. There is no inquiry selection window like the picture above.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog in question is part of Calendar.app and AppleScript is the only way to invoke it, but this is clunky. The best way is to create your own UI and use EventKit to add the event based on the selections in the UI.

Comment: I tried applescript, but it doesn’t seem to be able to do the function in the picture: a selection window appears

Comment: My point is you shouldn’t rely on this approach and should use the appropriate API. Your Electron app can even handle the UI.

Comment: The dialog is displayed when an ics file is opened. Can the dialog be displayed from AppleScript without an ics file?